# Can I describe the time like "eleven thirty hours"?

Tags: expressions

I'm reading now "Inherit the Stars". In the book there is a expression like this:

> "Make it round about eleven thirty hours," Gray advised.

Normally the "hours" is skipped, right?

Is this expression right English? Or is it just kind of SF language?